How many months validity do I need on my French passport to travel from EU to the UK?
My French passport is expiring in 2 months. This month I need to travel from EU to the UK for a short work trip (3 days).
The official border control web page states that

Your identity document should be valid for the whole of your stay.

The website of the French consulate in the UK says roughly the same.
While it appears to be the case for my passport, I couldn't find an exact definition of "valid". Other websites have blurred lines, mentioning a recommended remaining validity of 6 months. Some of these websites sell passport services, so I am not sure if they are reliable sources.
Can I safely use my passport or should I take action right now to make sure I can enter - trying to renew it quickly, contacting the French consulate in the UK for confirmation, asking my employer for an official document, etc.?

The “other websites” just mix up requirements for people coming to the UK and those for British citizens travelling abroad in some weird salad.

Have you done a search of this site? This question or one like it for other EU country citizens has been asked several times.

@Willeke I have, and couldn't find an exact match. The approaching questions were pre-Brexit.

"Valid" means "valid as determined by the passport's expiration date."  In other words, "valid for the whole of your stay" means the expiration date must fall on the day of your departure or later.
Where a country requires an additional period of validity after departure, the requirement is typically expressed as "must be valid for three months beyond the anticipated date of departure."  Where the required validity period is measured from the date of entry, that is typically either mentioned implicitly ("must be valid for at least six months") or explicitly ("must be valid for at least six months from the date of entry."

Can I safely use my passport

Yes.
